# Creating friend functions

Tags: c++

I'm learning about friend functions and I was wondering how I could create a friend function in this code to print out the age, and irascibility of the Cat object.

```
#ifndef CAT H
#define CAT H

#include <string>

class Cat
{
    private :
        std :: string name ;
        int age ;
        float irascibility ;
    public :
    void setName(std :: string n) {name = n;}
    std :: string getName ( ) {return name ; }
    void setAge(int a) {age = a;}
    int getAge( ) {return age ;}
    void setIrascibility (float i) {irascibility = i;}
    float getIrascibility ( ){return irascibility;}
    
    std :: string meow(int rep)
    {
        std :: string output = " " ;
        for (int i { 0 } ; i < rep − 1 ; i++)
            output += "MEOW" ;
        if ( rep != 0 )
            output += "MEOW" ;
        return output ;
    }

};

#end if
```

Comment: I don't see why a `friend` function should be necessary with your code? There are `public` getters for all the internal data.

Comment: Everyone knows cats don't have friends. They only have staff.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Cat` class already has getters for all its data, just declare those as `const` and create a regular operator overload.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cat& cat) {
    return os << "Cat [name=" << cat.getName() << ", age=" << cat.getAge() << ']';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Cat
{
public:
    void setName(std::string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void setAge(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    void setIrascibility(float i)
    {
        irascibility = i;
    }

    float getIrascibility()
    {
        return irascibility;
    }

    std::string meow(int rep)
    {
        std::string output = " ";
        for (int i{0}; i < rep - 1; i++)
            output += "MEOW";
        if (rep != 0)
            output += "MEOW";
        return output;
    }

    friend void printAge(const Cat &cat);
    friend void printIrascibility(const Cat &cat);

private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    float irascibility;
};

void printAge(const Cat &cat)
{
    std::cout << cat.age << std::endl;
}

void printIrascibility(const Cat &cat)
{
    std::cout << cat.irascibility << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

But, friend functions are not needed here. although the class properties are private, it has public getters for these properties. Honestly I would do this class like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Cat
{
    std::string meow(size_t rep)
    {
        std::string output{};

        for (size_t i{0}; i < rep; i++)
            output += "MEOW";

        return output;
    }

    std::string name;
    int age;
    float irascibility;
};

inline void printAge(const Cat &cat) noexcept
{
    std::cout << cat.age << std::endl;
}

inline void printIrascibility(const Cat &cat) noexcept
{
    std::cout << cat.irascibility << std::endl;
}
```

I recommend you to read more c++ code, practice and more practice. Sorry for any mistake.